# Evaluate a dynamic expression with sprintf in R

Tags: r, printf

I'm trying to create a expression dynamically before its evaluation in the following way:

```
authors <- c("John1","John2")
exp1 <- "(Author1==%s & Author2==%s)"
```

I would like to get the following string:

```
desired_output <- "(Author1==\"John1\" & Author2!=\"John2\")"
```

, that can then be evaluated with eval().

I have tried: `sprintf(exp1,authors)` , but that doesn't work... what is the solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
library(plyr)
splat(sprintf)(c(exp1, authors))
```

Or without a library:

```
do.call(sprintf,as.list(c(exp1,authors)))
```